# How to detect touch on NSTextAttachment

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nstextattachment

What is the best way to detect when user taps on `NSTextAttachment` on iOS?

I think that one of the ways would be checking for the character on carret's position whether it is `NSAttachmentCharacter`, but it just doesn't seem right.

I've also tried `UITextViewDelegate` method: `-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithTextAttachment:(NSTextAttachment *)textAttachment inRange:(NSRange)characterRange` but it's not invoked when `textView.editable=YES`

Comment: Hi Michal, I have the exact same issue now & want to be able to detect taps & touches on `NSTextAttachment`'s even when `textView.editable=YES` - Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The delegate method does work but ONLY if the attachment has an image in the image attribute AND if editable = NO!  So if you have an image pasted in to the attributedString from somewhere else it seems the data ends up being stored in the fileWrapper and next time you put the attributedString back into the textView the image attribute is nil and the layout manager or whatever gets the image from the fileWrapper.

Somewhere in the documents it does mention that there are no methods in NSTextAttachment for persistence of the image attribute.

To test this try copy a photo from the Photo app and paste it into your textView, now if you hold down your finger on it you should see the default menu pop up. Now if you save this rich text, say into a Core Data entity and then retrieve it the image attribute will be nil but the image data will be in `attachment.fileWrapper.regularFileContents`

Its a pain, and I would love to know the engineers intention.  So you have two options it seems.

1. Create your own custom NSTextAttachment and include methods for archiving the image and other settings (PLEASE SHOW ME HOW TOO WHEN YOU FIGURE THIS ONE OUT)
2. Every time prior to putting your string back into textView you find all the attachments and recreated the image attribute like so:

   attachment.image = [UIImage imageWithData:attachment.fileWrapper.regularFileContents];

Bear in mind the side effect of doing this is invalidating the fileWrapper.  I want to resize the image but also keep the original so I don't loose the full resolution.  I think the only way of doing this might be to subclass NSTextAttachment.

EDIT:

I figured out how to create the custom NSTextAttachments - here is a link for those interested http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/implementing-rich-text-with-images-on-os-x-and-ios/

EDIT 2: To customise the menu when in Edit Mode see the following Apple documents, the issue is 'touchEnded' never seems to get called so you might have to try using touchesBegan.  Careful you don't interfere with the default editing behaviour though.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/AddingCustomEditMenuItems/AddingCustomEditMenuItems.html

Note that in the code below you would need to add code after `// selection management` comment to determine which character was touched, check if it is the special text attachment character and
then modify the edit menu or take some other action.

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *theTouch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([theTouch tapCount] == 2  && [self becomeFirstResponder]) {

        // selection management code goes here...

        // bring up edit menu.
        UIMenuController *theMenu = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
        CGRect selectionRect = CGRectMake (currentSelection.x, currentSelection.y, SIDE, SIDE);
        [theMenu setTargetRect:selectionRect inView:self];
        [theMenu setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];

    }
}
```

Alternately you could add a custom menu by adding the menu item and then modifying the canPerformAction method.

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    LOG(@"canPerformAction: called");

    if (action == @selector(viewImage)) {
       // Check the selected character is the special text attachment character

       return YES;
    }
   return NO;
}
```

Here is some addition code but its a bit fussy.  Second method just disables the default edit menu if an attachment is detected.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    FLOG(@"touchesBegan:withEvent: called");

    if (self.selectedRange.location != NSNotFound) {
        FLOG(@" selected location is %d", self.selectedRange.location);

        int ch;

        if (self.selectedRange.location >= self.textStorage.length) {
            // Get the character at the location
            ch = [[[self textStorage] string] characterAtIndex:self.selectedRange.location-1];
        } else {
            // Get the character at the location
            ch = [[[self textStorage] string] characterAtIndex:self.selectedRange.location];
        }

        if (ch == NSAttachmentCharacter) {
            FLOG(@" selected character is %d, a TextAttachment", ch);
        } else {
            FLOG(@" selected character is %d", ch);
        }
    }

}
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    FLOG(@"canPerformAction: called");

        FLOG(@" selected location is %d", self.selectedRange.location);
        FLOG(@" TextAttachment character is %d", NSAttachmentCharacter);

        if (self.selectedRange.location != NSNotFound) {

            int ch;

            if (self.selectedRange.location >= self.textStorage.length) {
                // Get the character at the location
                ch = [[[self textStorage] string] characterAtIndex:self.selectedRange.location-1];
            } else {
                // Get the character at the location
                ch = [[[self textStorage] string] characterAtIndex:self.selectedRange.location];
            }

            if (ch == NSAttachmentCharacter) {
                FLOG(@" selected character is %d, a TextAttachment", ch);
                return NO;
            } else {
                FLOG(@" selected character is %d", ch);
            }

            // Check for an attachment
            NSTextAttachment *attachment = [[self textStorage] attribute:NSAttachmentAttributeName atIndex:self.selectedRange.location effectiveRange:NULL];
            if (attachment) {
                FLOG(@" attachment attribute retrieved at location %d", self.selectedRange.location);
                return NO;
            }
            else
                FLOG(@" no attachment at location %d", self.selectedRange.location);
        }
    return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i think the original question was how to make detect the touch even when `textView.editable = YES` is set.

Comment: That is possible using the same approach that is used to display the text editing popup menu.  You have to check if the selected character is the special text attachment character - I'll see if I can find an example.

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald - Large portions of this answer seem to have absolutely no bearing on the question.

Comment: -1: Utter garbage. This doesn't detect whether you touched an attachment. It detects if the character after your cursor (or before it, if your cursor is at the end) is an attachment. If your attachment is in the middle of a body of text and you select after it, it'll say you didn't select it.

Comment: Strong words.  This might be an option http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203690/xcode-how-to-make-a-pop-up-menu/20203915#20203915

Answer (score 7):

Josh's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52883387/658604) is almost perfect. However, if you tap in the whitespace of your UITextView past the end of the input, **glyphIndex(for:in:fractionOfDistanceThroughGlyph)** will return the final glyph in the string. If this is your attachment, it will incorrectly evaluate to true.

Apple's docs say: *If no glyph is under point, the nearest glyph is returned, where nearest is defined according to the requirements of selection by mouse. Clients who wish to determine whether the the point actually lies within the bounds of the glyph returned should follow this with a call to boundingRect(forGlyphRange:in:) and test whether the point falls in the rectangle returned by that method.*

So, here is a tweaked version (Swift 5, XCode 10.2) that performs an additional check on the bounds of the detected glyph. I believe some of the *characterIndex* tests are now superfluous but they don't hurt anything.

One caveat: glyphs appear to extend to the height of the line containing them. If you have a tall portrait image attachment next to a landscape image attachment, taps on the whitespace above the landscape image will still evaluate to true.

```
import UIKit
import UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerSubclass

// Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/52883387/658604
// and https://stackoverflow.com/a/49153247/658604

/// Recognizes a tap on an attachment, on a UITextView.
/// The UITextView normally only informs its delegate of a tap on an attachment if the text view is not editable, or a long tap is used.
/// If you want an editable text view, where you can short cap an attachment, you have a problem.
/// This gesture recognizer can be added to the text view, and will add requirments in order to recognize before any built-in recognizers.
class AttachmentTapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer {

    typealias TappedAttachment = (attachment: NSTextAttachment, characterIndex: Int)

    private(set) var tappedState: TappedAttachment?

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        tappedState = nil

        guard let textView = view as? UITextView else {
            state = .failed
            return
        }

        if let touch = touches.first {
            tappedState = evaluateTouch(touch, on: textView)
        }

        if tappedState != nil {
            // UITapGestureRecognizer can accurately differentiate discrete taps from scrolling
            // Therefore, let the super view evaluate the correct state.
            super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

        } else {
            // User didn't initiate a touch (tap or otherwise) on an attachment.
            // Force the gesture to fail.
            state = .failed
        }
    }

    /// Tests to see if the user has tapped on a text attachment in the target text view.
    private func evaluateTouch(_ touch: UITouch, on textView: UITextView) -> TappedAttachment? {
        let point = touch.location(in: textView)
        let glyphIndex: Int = textView.layoutManager.glyphIndex(for: point, in: textView.textContainer, fractionOfDistanceThroughGlyph: nil)
        let glyphRect = textView.layoutManager.boundingRect(forGlyphRange: NSRange(location: glyphIndex, length: 1), in: textView.textContainer)
        guard glyphRect.contains(point) else {
            return nil
        }
        let characterIndex: Int = textView.layoutManager.characterIndexForGlyph(at: glyphIndex)
        guard characterIndex < textView.textStorage.length else {
            return nil
        }
        guard NSTextAttachment.character == (textView.textStorage.string as NSString).character(at: characterIndex) else {
            return nil
        }
        guard let attachment = textView.textStorage.attribute(.attachment, at: characterIndex, effectiveRange: nil) as? NSTextAttachment else {
            return nil
        }
        return (attachment, characterIndex)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer but it provides wrong indices if you have textContainerInset on the textView, make sure you add the difference to the point like this: 
`let touch = touch.location(in: textView)`
`let point = CGPoint(x: touch.x - textView.textContainerInset.left, y: touch.y - textView.textContainerInset.top)`
instead of : `let point = touch.location(in: textView)`

Answer (score 4):

Apple make this really difficult. As others point out, the delegate method is called, but only when `isEditable` is `false`, or when the user does a tap and hold on the attachment. If you want to be informed about a simple tap interaction during editing, forget it.

I went down the `touchesBegan:` and `hitTest:` paths, both with problems. The touches methods are called *after* the `UITextView` has already handled the interaction, and the `hitTest:` is too crude, because it messes with the first responder status and so forth.

My solution in the end was gesture recognizers. Apple are using those internally, which explains why `touchesBegan:` is not really viable in the first place: the gesture recognizers have already handled the event.

I created a new gesture recognizer class for use with a `UITextView`. It simply checks for the location of the tap, and if it is an attachment, it handles it. I make all the other gesture recognizers subordinate to my one, so we get first look at the events, and the others only come into play if our one fails.

The gesture recognizer class is below, along with an extension for adding it to `UITextView`. I add it in my `UITextView` subclass in `awakeFromNib`, like this. (You needn't use a subclass if you don't have one.)

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    let recognizer = AttachmentTapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleAttachmentTap(_:)))
    add(recognizer)
```

and I handle the action by calling the existing `UITextViewDelegate` method `textView(_:,shouldInteractWith:,in:,interaction:)`. You could just as easily put the handling code directly in the action, rather than using the delegate.

```
@IBAction func handleAttachmentTap(_ sender: AttachmentTapGestureRecognizer) {
    let _ = delegate?.textView?(self, shouldInteractWith: sender.attachment!, in: NSRange(location: sender.attachmentCharacterIndex!, length: 1), interaction: .invokeDefaultAction)
}
```

Here is the main class.

```
import UIKit
import UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerSubclass

/// Recognizes a tap on an attachment, on a UITextView.
/// The UITextView normally only informs its delegate of a tap on an attachment if the text view is not editable, or a long tap is used.
/// If you want an editable text view, where you can short cap an attachment, you have a problem.
/// This gesture recognizer can be added to the text view, and will add requirments in order to recognize before any built-in recognizers.
class AttachmentTapGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer {

    /// Character index of the attachment just tapped
    private(set) var attachmentCharacterIndex: Int?

    /// The attachment just tapped
    private(set) var attachment: NSTextAttachment?

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        attachmentCharacterIndex = nil
        attachment = nil

        let textView = view as! UITextView
        if touches.count == 1, let touch = touches.first, touch.tapCount == 1 {
            let point = touch.location(in: textView)
            let glyphIndex: Int? = textView.layoutManager.glyphIndex(for: point, in: textView.textContainer, fractionOfDistanceThroughGlyph: nil)
            let index: Int? = textView.layoutManager.characterIndexForGlyph(at: glyphIndex ?? 0)
            if let characterIndex = index, characterIndex < textView.textStorage.length {
                if NSAttachmentCharacter == (textView.textStorage.string as NSString).character(at: characterIndex) {
                    attachmentCharacterIndex = characterIndex
                    attachment = textView.textStorage.attribute(.attachment, at: characterIndex, effectiveRange: nil) as? NSTextAttachment
                    state = .recognized
                } else {
                    state = .failed
                }
            }
        } else {
            state = .failed
        }
    }
}

extension UITextView {

    /// Add an attachment recognizer to a UITTextView
    func add(_ attachmentRecognizer: AttachmentTapGestureRecognizer) {
        for other in gestureRecognizers ?? [] {
            other.require(toFail: attachmentRecognizer)
        }
        addGestureRecognizer(attachmentRecognizer)
    }

}
```

This same approach could presumably be used for taps on links.

Comment: Slightly modified your code and posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52883387/658604

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3 answer:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith textAttachment: NSTextAttachment, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Make sure your textView `isEditable = false`, `isSelectable = true`, and `isUserInteractionEnabled = true`.   Duncan's answer did not mention `isUserInteractionEnabled`, this has to be `true`, otherwise it wont work.

You can do this programmatically (textView.isEditable = false), or via attributes inspector: 
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I have altered Drew's gesture recognizer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49153247/658604) to subclass `UITapGestureRecognizer` rather than `UIGestureRecognizer`.

This offers one advantage in that it only detects discrete taps as opposed to the beginning of a scroll.

```
import UIKit
import UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerSubclass

// Modified from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49153247/658604

/// Recognizes a tap on an attachment, on a UITextView.
/// The UITextView normally only informs its delegate of a tap on an attachment if the text view is not editable, or a long tap is used.
/// If you want an editable text view, where you can short cap an attachment, you have a problem.
/// This gesture recognizer can be added to the text view, and will add requirments in order to recognize before any built-in recognizers.
class AttachmentTapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer {

    typealias TappedAttachment = (attachment: NSTextAttachment, characterIndex: Int)

    private(set) var tappedState: TappedAttachment?

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        tappedState = nil

        guard let textView = view as? UITextView else {
            state = .failed
            return
        }

        if let touch = touches.first {
            tappedState = evaluateTouch(touch, on: textView)
        }

        if tappedState != nil {
            // UITapGestureRecognizer can accurately differentiate discrete taps from scrolling
            // Therefore, let the super view evaluate the correct state.
            super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

        } else {
            // User didn't initiate a touch (tap or otherwise) on an attachment.
            // Force the gesture to fail.
            state = .failed
        }
    }

    /// Tests to see if the user has tapped on a text attachment in the target text view.
    private func evaluateTouch(_ touch: UITouch, on textView: UITextView) -> TappedAttachment? {
        let point = touch.location(in: textView)
        let glyphIndex: Int? = textView.layoutManager.glyphIndex(for: point, in: textView.textContainer, fractionOfDistanceThroughGlyph: nil)
        let index: Int? = textView.layoutManager.characterIndexForGlyph(at: glyphIndex ?? 0)
        guard let characterIndex = index, characterIndex < textView.textStorage.length else {
            return nil
        }
        guard NSTextAttachment.character == (textView.textStorage.string as NSString).character(at: characterIndex) else {
            return nil
        }
        guard let attachment = textView.textStorage.attribute(.attachment, at: characterIndex, effectiveRange: nil) as? NSTextAttachment else {
            return nil
        }
        return (attachment, characterIndex)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer Josh. I made a small improvement to better handle attachments at the end of the input string: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55854337/1758224

Comment: @Josh-Fuggle I am struggle to use your code. I copy past and run it give errors. I am using swift 3. Can you guide?

Answer (score 2):

SWIFT 4.2

```
@objc func myMethodToHandleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

let myTextView = sender.view as! UITextView

     let layoutManager = myTextView.layoutManager

     // location of tap in myTextView coordinates and taking the inset into account
     var location = sender.location(in: myTextView)
     location.x -= myTextView.textContainerInset.left;
     location.y -= myTextView.textContainerInset.top;

     // character index at tap location
     let characterIndex = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: location, in: myTextView.textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)

     if characterIndex < myTextView.textStorage.length {

        let attributeValue = myTextView.attributedText.attribute(NSAttributedString.Key.attachment, at: characterIndex, effectiveRange: nil) as? NSTextAttachment

        if let _ = attributeValue {
           print("TAPPED ATTACHMENT")  
        }
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use hitTest to get the touch in a subclassed UITextView. This avoids the issue of messing up the standard editing functions. From the position get the character index and then check the character for the attachment.

Answer (score 0):

I found the common way to solve this kind of clicking attachment in attributed string is using UITextView . But the UITextView is so complicated to disable all the menu, the zoom and so on . So I make a simple version of UILabel wrapper to support attachment clicking . It's simple and easy to use&change . the demo is here:

```
self.attachmentLabel.attributeText = attributeText;
self.attachmentLabel.numberOflines = 2;
self.attachmentLabel.selectBlock = ^(NSInteger attachmentIndex) {
    NSLog(@"attachment:%ld called",attachmentIndex);
};
```

https://github.com/ximmyxiao/TestAttributeStringClick

Hope it will helps:）

[image]