# Xcode - How to make a pop up menu

Tags: ios, xcode, popup

I would like to make a pop up menu in Xcode. How can I do it? I would like it to look nice and professional.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is an example of using UIActionSheet to present a popup menu in a UITextView in response to a longPress on an attachment.

```
- (void)attachmentActionSheet:(UITextView *)textView range:(NSRange)range {

    // get the rect for the selected attachment (if its a big image with top not visible the action sheet
    // will be positioned above the top limit of the UITextView
    // Need to add code to adjust for this.
    CGRect attachmentRect = [self frameOfTextRange:range inTextView:textView];

      _attachmentMenuSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                             destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                  otherButtonTitles:@"Copy Image", @"Save to Camera Roll", @"Open in Viewer", nil];

    // Show the sheet
    [_attachmentMenuSheet showFromRect:attachmentRect inView:textView animated:YES];
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (actionSheet == _attachmentMenuSheet) {
        //FLOG(@"Button %d", buttonIndex);
        switch (buttonIndex) {

            case 0:
                //FLOG(@" Copy Image");
                [self copyImageToPasteBoard:[_attachment image]];
                break;

            case 1:
                //FLOG(@"  Save to Camera Roll");
                [self saveToCameraRoll:[_attachment image]];
                break;

            case 2:
                //FLOG(@"  Open in Viewer");
                [self browseImage:[_attachment image]];
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is what it looks like on the iPad and iPhone (iOS7)

[image]

[image]

Comment: @DanYaRon the protocol here is to accept the answer if its what you were looking for.