# How to get following pop up menu in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to have a similar pop up menu when the user presses the button

[image]

How do I implement it?

---

The only similar post I've come across is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203690/xcode-how-to-make-a-pop-up-menu), but alas, it is not written in Swift

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UIAlertController - add custom views to actionsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32790207/uialertcontroller-add-custom-views-to-actionsheet)

Comment: @kjoe, it does, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That is called a UIAlertController, using `.actionSheet` style. See

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller

for more info.