# clickable image inside textview

Tags: swift3, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I am using attributed string to add image/text inside a textview, that's working great hence the picture below. I would like to know if there's a way to make that image clickabel to perform some function. Or if there's a way to add some clickable button inside the textview to perform some function. Anything help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance...

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43330821/1801544 ?

Comment: @Larme thanks for your response, but this will not work. Because I want the textview to be editible. This solution said the textview isEditable = false.

Comment: Did you check the other solutions? It's custom made, but seems to work since it has been flagged as the solution.

Comment: @Larme I made a few changes and it worked, but only when I long pressed the image not on tapped. Thanks for your help....