# Swift NSTextAttachment with Tap recognition inside TextView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsattributedstring, nstextattachment

**Problem:**

How can I recognize tap recognition on a NSTextAttachment?

I have a image attachment that is appended to the end of an AttributedString on a textView inside a tableView cell.

How can I add a tap gesture **ONLY** to the attachment itself?

**Code:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ChatTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ChatTableViewCell
        let attachment = messageData[indexPath.row].attachment
          
            let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString()
            let attributedText2 = NSMutableAttributedString(string: messageData[indexPath.row].message + "\n\n")
            
            attributedText2.append(NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment))
            attributedText2.append(attributedText)
            cell.chatTextView.attributedText = attributedText2

            return cell  
    }
```

**PSEUDO:**

```
attachment.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tap(recognizer:))))
```

**Other notes:**

I can add a gesture recognizer to the textView, or text in the textview. Im just not sure how to add a tap gesture specifically to the attachment itself.

**Platform:**

-iOS, Swift

Comment: I need an example in my particular case. Im not sure I fully understand.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect touch on NSTextAttachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19318092/how-to-detect-touch-on-nstextattachment)

Comment: Did you implement `textView(_:shouldInteractWith:in:interaction:)`?

Answer (score -4):

I think you have to set "add gesture recognizer"

cell.chatTextView.tag = indexPath.row
cell.chatTextView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tap(recognizer:))))

and make sure you have set the tag before the add tap gesture.

Comment: If you had read my post, it says, "I can add a gesture recognizer to the textView, or text in the textview. Im just not sure how to add a tap gesture specifically to the attachment itself."